# JQuery SelectBox in Sortable Table does not work

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to sort a Table that includes SelectBoxes.
When I make the Table sortable, then the SelectBoxes does not Drop down.

This JQuery and UI Versions are in use ...
jquery-1.9.1.js
jquery-ui-1.9.1.js

I hope someone can help me.

Here is the code ...

HTML

```
    <table id="sort">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AAA</th>
            <th>BBB</th>
            <th>CCC</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>222</td>
            <td>
                <select name="s1">
                    <option value="1">v1</option>
                    <option value="2">v2</option>
                    <option value="3">v3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>333</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>
                <select name="s2">
                    <option value="1">v1</option>
                    <option value="2">v2</option>
                    <option value="3">v3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>555</td>
            <td>666</td>
            <td>
                <select name="s3">
                    <option value="1">v1</option>
                    <option value="2">v2</option>
                    <option value="3">v3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
            $( 'div[id$=_pos_view]' ).each(function( index ) {
                $(this).html(index);
            });     

            $("input:checkbox[name$=__active]").each(function( index ) {
                $(this).data('pos', index);
            });     
    }
}).disableSelection();

</script>
```

Comment: could you make a fiddle for this @ jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: hi hungerpain you can look at http://jsfiddle.net/PKCF9/ ... the problem ist that sorting works, but i can not open the selct box ... tahnx Talki

Comment: It seems to working for me..what browser are u testing this on?

Comment: I just tested the IE10, here it works ...
but not in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve this by just adding this line

```
 $("ul.ef_sortable").sortable({
      cancel: "select"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue. You have to remove

```
.disableSelection()
```

[See support ticket #8947](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8947)

Also check the updated http://jsfiddle.net/PKCF9/2/

Comment: your welcome, if you think the answer was useful, please accept it so it's easier for others to find..